# Avoid trailing whitespace when copy/pasting from bash/byobu terminal

Tags: bash, byobu, paste, echo

I wrote a `bash` script that computes information and `echo`es it into my `byobu` terminal.
I then select the whole thing with my mouse and paste it into a Gmail conversation after editing it a bit.

**Problem**: There are a lot of whitespace characters at the end of each line.

**Question**: Is there any I can do to prevent this? Maybe using a different shell, or a different terminal emulator, or a different copy technique?

Notes:

- I could make my script echo into a file, then open that file in a text editor and copy/paste its content, but that would waste too much time.
- Strangely the number of trailing spaces seems pretty random. It does not seem to match the number of spaces between the last character of each line and the right border of the terminal window.

Sample code:

```
echo "The acidity level is ${ACIDITY} with a precision of ${PRECISION}."
echo "This is in the range of ${RANGE_EXPLANATION}."
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218248/70524

Comment: @muru: Thanks for the tip! So it seems that Byobu is inserting such whitespace for performance reasons... I hope there is a shortcut to make it reset and redraw the whole window. I will add an `xsel` call, but it is not a perfect solution as I often have other things to copy/paste between running the script and writing the email.

Comment: `s/Byobu/tmux`, and going by Thomas Dickey's answer, screen does support this feature, so you can tell Byobu to run screen instead of tmux.